# Group events in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I would like to process two events in wxPython.  Specifically, I would like to group the `ON_KEY_DOWN` and `CHAR` events to call a method with information on what key was pressed and what (if anything) this character would yield.

Quoting the documentation:

> While both of these functions can be used with the events of wxEVT_KEY_DOWN , wxEVT_KEY_UP and wxEVT_CHAR types, the values returned by them are different for the first two events and the last one. For the latter, the key returned corresponds to the character that would appear in e.g. a text zone if the user pressed the key in it. As such, its value depends on the current state of the Shift key and, for the letters, on the state of Caps Lock modifier. For example, if A key is pressed without Shift being held down, wx.KeyEvent of type wxEVT_CHAR generated for this key press will return (from either GetKeyCode or GetUnicodeKey as their meanings coincide for ASCII characters) key code of 97 corresponding the ASCII value of a . And if the same key is pressed but with Shift being held (or Caps Lock being active), then the key could would be 65, i.e. ASCII value of capital A . However for the key down and up events the returned key code will instead be A independently of the state of the modifier keys i.e. it depends only on physical key being pressed and is not translated to its logical representation using the current keyboard state.

The trouble is I would like to have both information.  If a key is pressed I would like to have the "raw key code" such as KEY_UP or KLEY_DOWN would yield, and the typed character (if any) corresponding.  I've tried to come up with a solution.  But `CHAR` is not raised all the time (some key presses just wouldn't yield any character).

> The documentation gives the shift and CapLock example, which is somewhat odd.  Consider, however, that not all users have a QWERTY keyboard.  And this makes much more sense: if a user with an AZERTY keyboard presses on the letter corresponding to the 1 digit in QWERTY, then a & would be written (KEY_DOWN.KeyCode would yield `'1'` while `CHAR.KeyCode` would yield `&`.  Does it make more sense?

So how to intercept both events and call one and a single method with both information (being understood that `CHAR` would not always be raised)?

I thought I had found a solution: if I can access the event loop, or the event handler's queue of events, maybe I could check: if a `KEY_DOWN` event is raised, then I check if the next event is `CHAR` and, if so, retrieve the needed information from `CHAR` and calls a single method.  But I don't see how to do it and the documentation doesn't (as far as I can tell) exactly describe when the `CHAR` event is raised (it might not be exactly after `KEY_DOWN`, it might be just before `KEU_UP` or somewhere father down the line).

Another possibility would be to "force" wx to "convert" a `KEY_DOWN` event into a `CHAR` event.  Again, this sounds very specific and I couldn't find how to do that.  All in all, what I need is to convert a "raw key code" to the system "typed character", I don't need the full events either.

### Code sample

obviouvlsy, I can't write the code, but here's a tiny example of what I would like to achieve:

```
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Type something here")
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.label)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        # Binding isn't possible
        #self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.OnKeyDown)

    def OnKeyDown(self, keycode, unicode=None):
        """
        The `keycode` key was pressed.

        It generated (if anything) the `unicode` character.

        """
        print(f"The {key_code} was pressed, generating the {unicode} character.")

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = TestPanel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

The challenge here is to connect the text field to the `OnKeyDown` method in a way where BOTH the key code and unicode key are transmitted.  (The `GetUnincodeKey()` on `EVT_KEY_DOWN` doesn't do the trick, it is strictly equivalent to `key_code` which doesn't helpme).

To recap, if you press a on your keyboard, key_code should be 65 (uppercase A) and unicode should be 97 (lowercase a), except if caplock is on.  And if you're using a different layout than QWERTY, unicode should always be the letter that will appear in the text (and this information in only given in the `CHAR` event).  Hope that clarifies!

Answer (score 2):

Without code sometimes it is difficult to visualise what it is that you are attempting to do.
I think that what you are missing is `event.Skip()`

`Skip()`

> This method can be used inside an event handler to control whether further event handlers bound to this event will be called after the current one returns
>   Without Skip (or equivalently if Skip(false) is used), the event will not be processed any more. If Skip(true) is called, the event processing system continues searching for a further handler function for this event, even though it has been processed already in the current handler.

Also, from the documentation:

> GetUnicodeKey(self)
>   Returns the Unicode character corresponding to this key event.
>
> If the key pressed doesn’t have any character value (e.g. a cursor key) this method will return WXK_NONE . In this case you should use GetKeyCode to retrieve the value of the key.

So we can bind the following to KEY_DOWN, KEY_UP and CHAR:

```
def EvtKey(self, event):
    if event.GetUnicodeKey():
        print("A value key")
        print(chr(event.GetUnicodeKey()))
    else:
        print("a key event")
        print(event.GetKeyCode())
    event.Skip()
```

Edit due to your comment:
I suggest that you take a look and `EVT_CHAR` and `EVT_CHAR_HOOK`

```
import wx

class TestPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.label = wx.StaticText(self, label="Type something here")
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.sizer.Add(self.label)
        self.sizer.Add(self.text)
        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)

        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR, self.OnKeyDown)
        # The choice here will depend on exactly what you want
        # CHAR_HOOK will additionally give shift, ctrl, alt etc
        #self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK, self.OnKeyDown)

    def OnKeyDown(self, event):
        key_code = event.GetUnicodeKey()
        control_key = event.GetKeyCode()
        if key_code == 0:
            print(f"The control key {control_key} was pressed.")
        else:
            unicode = chr(key_code)
            """
            The `keycode` key was pressed.

            It generated (if anything) the `unicode` character.

            """
            print(f"The {key_code} was pressed, generating the {unicode} character.")
        event.Skip()

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = TestPanel(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem.  I have added an incomplete code sample, hope that helps to show what I want to achieve.

Comment: @vincent-lg I have added an alternative to my original answer

Comment: thanks so much.  I had no idea this event even existed.  I guess I need help navigating the wxPython's doc.  I'm not sure it would be usable for me, but this seems to be easier than what I was considering.